# How to retrieve the string from the html source code using ruby regular expression? <span class="bz_comment_time">22:11:43 PDT </span>

Tags: html, ruby, regex

I have the following code in my html file.

22:11:43 PDT

I want the following as an output:
   22:11:43 PDT

Answer (score 1):

```
your_html_source[/22:11:43 PDT/] # => "22:11:43 PDT"
```

Comment: Thanks. But we have many dates in that HTML file. I want to display all the dates.                                                  <span class=“bz_comment_time”>26:00:23 PDT </span>              <span class=“bz_comment_time”>12:10:33 PDT </span>                <span class=“bz_comment_time”>23:11:48 PDT </span>

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
"<span class='bz_comment_time'>22:11:43 PDT </span>".gsub!(/<\/?[^>]*>/,"")

 => "22:11:43 PDT "
```